# PHP reading lines from file and compare them

Tags: php, file, strpos

I am trying to read all lines from a file and than see if a given string contains any of these lines.

My code

```
$mails = file('blacklist.txt');

$email = "hendrik@anonbox.net";

$fail = false;
foreach($mails as $mail) {
    if(strpos($email, $mail) > 0) {
        $fail = true;
    }
}
if($fail) {
    echo "Fail";
} else {
    echo "you can use that";
}
```

The `blacklist.txt` can be found here http://pastebin.com/aJyVkcNx.

I would expect `strpos` return a position for at least one string in the blacklist, but it does not. I am guessing that somehow I am generating not the kind of values within the `$mails` as I am expecting.

EDIT this is `print_r($mails)` http://pastebin.com/83ZqVwHx

EDIT2 some clarification: I want to see if a domain is within an email, even if the mail contains `subdomain.domain.tld`. And I tried to use `!== false` instead of my `> 0` which yielded the same result.

Comment: `strpos('a', 'abc') === 0`, the returned value is zero-based.

Comment: Yes, and I am aware of that. But in my case a mail should have at least a single character before the string I am looking for. Because I am looking for the part behind the @ in a mail.

Comment: hendrik@anonbox.net does not appear in that output

Comment: `$email` needs to be the exact string that you are looking for, using the strpos function. In your case, the exact string hendrik@anonbox.net does not appear in `$mails`, so will always return false

Comment: But can't strpos be used to look for a substring? That was my approach. To have a mail "hendrik@anonbox.net" and domain in "$mails" and check for each domain if it is a substring of "hendrik@anonbox.net".

Comment: I'm a little unclear of exactly what you want to do, but I'm pretty sure you want to use `strstr()`

Comment: @Alex doesn't that basically do the same as strpos() ? It find the first occurrence of a string within another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the email well since you're checking the domain of the email address if its inside the blacklist. Example:

```
$email = "hendrik@foo.anonbox.net";
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    preg_match('/@.*?([^.]+[.]\w{3}|[^.])$/', $email, $matches);
    if(!empty($matches) && isset($matches[1])) {
        $domain = $matches[1];
    } else {
        // not good email
        exit;
    }
    // THIS IS FOR SAMPLES SAKE, i know youre using file()
    $blacklist = explode("\n", file_get_contents('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aJyVkcNx'));
    foreach($blacklist as $email) {
        if(stripos($email, $domain) !== false) {
            echo 'you are blacklisted';
            exit;
        }
    }
}

// his/her email is ok continue
```

Comment: why add a sample and state "i know you're using file" and not actually show him a sample using file?

Comment: Wow that is working. When I try to use !== in my code however it does not. And I would like to also have "subdomain.blacklisted-domain.tld" be blacklisted, how would I go about that?

Comment: @DannyHearnah since i don't have the actual copy of the file i'l just use the live version, there's no problem on how to OP gets the blacklist so the OP will just adjust it accordingly.

Comment: @H_end-rik if `subdomain.blacklisted-domain.tld` will also be blacklisted what should be the needle this time?

Comment: @Ghost not really sure. When I use "hendrik@foo.anonbox.net" it does not say I am blacklisted.

Comment: @H_end-rik check revision, you need to parse the email well first, using regex (which im not good at)

Comment: This works perfectly, only need to understand all parts now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`strpos` returns `FALSE` if the string was not found.'

Simply use this :

```
$fail = false;
foreach($mails as $mail) {
    if(strpos($email, $mail) === false) {
        $fail = true;
    }
}
```

Or even better use this:

```
$blacklist = file_get_contents('blacklist.txt');

$email = "hendrik@anonbox.net";

if(strpos($email, $blacklist) === false){
    echo "fail";
} else {
    echo "This email is not blacklisted";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though you might still use `foreach`, that’s `array reduce` pattern:

```
function check_against($carry, $mail, $blacklisted) { 
  return $carry ||= strpos($mail, $blacklisted) !== false;
};

var_dump(array_reduce($mails, "check_against", $email_to_check));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I actually don't get that function at all. And it is missing a ;, copy pasting and using it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have found the common pitfall with the strpos function. The return value of the strpos function refers to the position at which it found the string. In this instance, if the string begins at the first character, it will return 0. **Note that 0 !== false**.

The correct way to use the function is:

```
if(strpos($email, $mail) !== false){
    // the string was found, potentially at position 0
}
```

However, this function may not be necessary at all; if you are simply checking if `$mail` is the same as `$email`, instead of seeing if the string exists within a larger string, then just use:

```
if($mail == $email){
    // they are the same
}
```

Comment: I tried that way first, with the same result of it not finding the pattern. And the string can not be found at position 0 due to this being email and me searching the the part behind the @.

Comment: please print_r($mails) and show the result  in your question

Comment: I would like to check for the domain only, as some trashmail providers give people subdomains. Therefor I would like to use strpos instead of a comparison.

Comment: Added that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to solve this. Works fine:

```
$blacklist = file_get_contents('blacklist.txt');
$email = "hendrik@x.ip6.li";
$domain = substr(trim($email), strpos($email, '@')+1);
if(strpos($blacklist, $domain)){
    echo "Your email has been blacklisted!";
}else{
    echo "You are all good to go! not blacklisted :-)";
}
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if the strings are not exactly the same.